# Temporary Coverage for Sand Driveway

Tags: driveway, cinderblock, cover

I have seen this done but never knew HOW it was done and remained in place. I am planning to gravel my sand driveway within the next month or so but in the meantime, I'm thinking about buying a heavy duty tarp to cover the sand (it's driving me crazy!) I was told to get cinder blocks to hold it in place but was wondering if there was a less conspicuous way to keep the tarp from blowing around (a huge blue or green tarp in the front yard is already ugly enough!). Also, recommendations on the type/brand of tarp would be helpful, as well!
Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: wrap some 2x4 lumber into the edges, so it acts as a frame

Comment: @jsotola now that could work...means I would have to get much larger tarp, though, which depending on cost of 2 of 2x4's and how many I need, could get a bit costly for temp fix. But thank you, I'll keep this idea in mind!

Comment: Do you want to use a tarp? Water will hold in the low spots.

Comment: I'm not sure the tarp is a good idea to begin with. As you drive, the sand will move and the tarp will develop loose areas. Eventually they'll be snagging on the vehicle. Instead of asking how to hold down a tarp, ask how to resolve your actual problem (which hasn't been made clear).

Comment: @EdBeal I thought about that...I'm open to suggestions! Again, it's temporary, only about a month or so...but I'm definitely open to ALL suggestions!

Comment: @isherwood The actual problem is covering the sand temporarily until I can get it graveled. It's driving me crazy because the sand always makes it into the house, in the car, etc!! :-(

Comment: Covering the sand is not a problem. It's a proposed solution. The problem is apparently that sand gets into your home.

Comment: Okay, technically you're correct...but even with taking our shoes off at the door (my kid is still struggling with this!) the sand still gets in the house not to mention, I'm vacuuming my car out every 2-3 days!  But again, I'm open to suggestions for another temp fix!

Answer (score 3):

6'' 11 Gauge HEAVY-DUTY U-Shaped Garden Staples

[image]

Comment: Maybe drive them in at opposing angles...  I've used these for holding down weed-cloth (what they are really made for), and they didn't seem to have a lot of grip.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Is weed cloth tougher than tarp? Do you think it will go through and hold the tarp? Or was the problem that they tore through cloth?

Comment: Weed cloth is lighter, and it's not that they tore through - the thin wire didn't seem to grip the soil very well.  It's a great suggestion, and cheap to try, but results are going to depend on your soil.  They won't rip through the tarp.